# Installing Open Source Reddit - pylonshq is down?

Tags: python, pylons, reddit

I'm trying to install a reddit clone. I'm following the guide https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/Install-guide found https://github.com/reddit/reddit.

I'm on this step:

```
sudo python setup.py develop
```

I see this in my logs:

> Reading http://www.pylonshq.com/download/
>
> Download error on http://www.pylonshq.com/download/: timed out -- Some
>   packages may not be found!

When I check the site http://www.pylonshq.com/ it was down, and when I searched about it people mentioned that it was down. What should I do when trying to install reddit? I understand I may be able to install pylons locally but how do I get my reddit install to pick those up (or is that even the correct way to resolve this problem)?

I cannot use the easy install script from reddit because I'm attempting to do this on my mac :(